# Why does this code leak memory?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos, cocoa, for-loop

I have some for cycle. In this cycle I made some request and get response text. In the end of loop I sleep thread for few seconds for some reason and continue iteration. There are about 500 objects in [Vk friends], so for repeats about 500 times, but when it finishing for my program use much more memory than at start up. I use ARC and I do not understand why memory allocated in the loop does not released every iteration? Is it normal, or maybe I am wrong?

```
for (Friend *friend in [Vk friends]) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"log" object:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Visit %i/%i friend (earn %i coins)", ++count, [Vk friends].count, [UserState coins] - coinsBefore]];
    if (friend.helpPoints <= 0) continue;
    strData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"someparams=somevalues&param1=%@", [Vk authKey]];
    data = [strData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://someaddress/somepath?somegetparams=%@", [Vk userId]]]];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.43 Safari/536.11" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    [request setValue:@"http://blahblah.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Origin"];
    [request setValue:@"http://blahblah.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Referer"];
    [request setValue:@"ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Language"];
    [request setValue:@"windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Charset"];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];
    data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
    doc = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:(helpTimeout + randDouble(min, max)) * 5.0];
}
```

Comment: All variables are declared above...

Answer (score 5):

Completely normal. If you feel that you're accumulating too much memory, wrap the interior of the for loop in an @autoreleasepool, so it reclaims memory at the end of each loop iteration.